# passing user object to function and then to prepared stament (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, object, mysqli, auto-increment

I'm fairly new to PHP, and I'm working with mysqli, OOP and prepared statements.

My question is this:

I'm trying to pass an user(object) to an Insert_user(func) in my database(class).

I have 3 classes, 'logic', 'data' and 'index'. Index includes data and logic, and initiates

the connection and user.

In my function (insert_user), I'm using an array to pass user variables into, before

binding and executing my statement.

Hers is my code:

```
<?php
function insert_user($user) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $binding = 'issssiisss'; 

    $variables = array( $user->user_id, $user->f_name, $user->l_name, $user->address,    $user->city, $user->zipcode, $user->mobile_number, $user->mail, $user->pass_key, $user->pass_word);

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param($binding,$variables[0],$variables[1],$variables[2],$variables[3],$variables[4],$variables[5],$variables[6],$variables[7],$variables[8],$variables[9]);

    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Here is my var_dump from browser:

```
object(user)#1 (10) { ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["f_name"]=> string(5) "pelle" ["l_name"]=>     string(5) "kanin" ["address"]=> string(7) "vænget" ["city"]=> string(6) "aaaaaa" ["zipcode"]=> int(123) ["mobile_number"]=> int(123) ["mail"]=> string(4) "fedt" ["pass_key"]=> string(3) "ert" ["pass_word"]=> string(4) "erto" } 

string(10) "issssiisss" 

array(10) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(5) "pelle" [2]=> string(5) "kanin" [3]=> string(7) "vænget" [4]=> string(6) "aaaaaa" [5]=> int(123) [6]=> int(123) [7]=> string(4) "fedt" [8]=> string(3) "ert" [9]=> string(4) "erto" } 

object(mysqli_stmt)#4 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(10) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

What am i doing wrong!?

Thank you.

EDIT: The problem is inserting the data into the database. It simply doesn't work. When i execute no data is put in.

I think the problem lies with the $stmt->bind_param function, and inserting the data from the array.

param_count = 10 and field_count = 0!

EDIT !2!:

OK. So, it actually works! what i did wrong was specify a integer value in my user_id, i.e. when i created the user. My database uses AUTO.INCREMENT on that value, and therefore it didn't work..

Anyways, thanks for the answer. G'day!

Comment: I am currently working on an "Easy MySQLi" class in php, where you will use arrays etc to upload data such as `$emsql->upload('TableName', Array('n;user_id', 's;user_name=Administrator', 's;user_pass=Password12'));`. Now where `n;` is NULL, and `s;` is String, and `i;` is Integer. and such as `user_name` and `user_pass` is coloumns in the table, and everything after `=` is content to upload. This class uses prepared statements. If you want to stay in touch for updates then just mail me at admin@theteamcoders.com

This domain is not yet up with a website, but the mail is working!

Answer (score -2):

Check if you have any errors when after each mysqli statement to isolate the error:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}    

$stmtBindResult = $stmt->bind_param($binding,$variables[0],$variables[1],$variables[2],$variables[3],$variables[4],$variables[5],$variables[6],$variables[7],$variables[8],$variables[9]);
if ( false===$stmtBindResult ) {
  die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmtExecuteResult = $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$stmtExecuteResult ) {
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
```

else you can use basic PDO. I would use PDO insert with following basic function:

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$Params = array($variables[0],$variables[1],$variables[2],$variables[3],$variables[4],$variables[5],$variables[6],$variables[7],$variables[8],$variables[9]);
$InsertResult = PDOInsert($Query, $Params);

function PDOInsert($Query, $Parameters)
{
    try 
    {
        $PDOConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.'', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $PDOConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $Statement = $PDOConnection->prepare($Query);
        foreach ($Parameters as $Key => $Val)
            $Statement->bindValue($Key+1, $Val);
        $Statement->execute();
        $PDOConnection = null;
        return true;
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: don't you find this `array($variables[n]` thing quite err... redundant?

Comment: Actually I do. Ideally I would avoid it but I just wanted to give an example on how I would start...

Comment: Well, you've got your start extremely inconsistent. It seems you need some more attempts until get it right

Comment: Point noted! But I am not entirely certain what kind of inconsistency?

Comment: 1. connecting every time you are about to run a query? 2. `$Params = array($variables[0]...` what's this? What's the point in such a toilsome duplication? Can't you just use $variables instead of $params? 3. can't you just pass $variables to execute()? 4.`die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());`  is evil. 5. $Params is not $Parameters.. etc.

Comment: 1. That is true. In this case I am assuming, there would be no other query in this script. 2. 100% agreed! I was thinking on the part if all variables are not already in array. 3. Obviously you would want to do something smart with error rather than kill the script, possibly return custom error message but again, this is just an example...

Comment: You could do nothing, mind you. And PHP will handle error better than this silly error revelation to an outsider. So - why give a bad example? Especially if it cost you extra lines of code?

Comment: Very true. That us how I did when starting learning. I really liked your criticism. Thank you. I will keep these things in mind for the future.